# Populate a single column with values from multiple table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables as follows:

Order_Table

```
| OrderID  | Type      | ItemID |
+----------+-----------+---------+
| 0001     | Car       | A001    |
| 0002     | Motorbike | A001    |
```

Car_Table

```
| ItemID  | ItemDesc   |
+---------+------------+
| A001    | Honda Jazz |
```

Motorbike_Table

```
| ItemID  | ItemDesc   |
+---------+------------+
| A001    | Yamaha F1Z |
```

I need to merge the last two tables into the first one by adding just a column called `ItemDesc`.

Is there any way I can do a query to populate the `ItemDesc` column from either `Car_Table` or `Motorbike_Table` depending on the value of the `Type` column?
Answer:

```
SELECT Order_Table.OrderID, Order_Table.Type, Order_Table.ItemID,
IIF(Order_Tbl.Type = "Car", Car_Tbl.ItemDesc, Motorbike_Tbl.ItemDesc) AS ItemDesc
FROM Order_Table 
LEFT JOIN Car_Table ON Order_Table.ItemID = Car_Table.ItemID
LEFT JOIN Motorbike_Table ON Order_Table.ItemID = Motorbike_Table.ItemID;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the result you want, selecting a value from `Car_table` when `Type = Car` and from `Motorbike_table` when `Type = Motorbike`:

```
SELECT Order_Table.OrderID, Order_Table.Type, Order_Table.ItemID,
IIF(Order_Tbl.Type = "Car", Car_Tbl.ItemDesc, Motorbike_Tbl.ItemDesc) AS ItemDesc
FROM Order_Table 
LEFT JOIN Car_Table ON Order_Table.ItemID = Car_Table.ItemID
LEFT JOIN Motorbike_Table ON Order_Table.ItemID = Motorbike_Table.ItemID;
```

Output:

```
OrderID     Type        ItemID  ItemDesc
1           Car         A001    Honda Jazz
2           Motorbike   A001    Yamaha F1Z
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7826f39bf134f6e82156802764204852)

Comment: Thanks Nick! I use the same logic, only changing the CASE clause with IIF as it is not supported by Ms Access

Comment: @DanielGinting I'm glad it's working. Apologies about the `CASE`, I'm not 100% familiar with Access and I thought `CASE` was pretty ubiquitous. You should edit the answer to what you used so that if any other Access users see it they won't get misled.

Comment: Good idea! Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.Type, o.ItemID, c.ItemDesc
FROM Order_Table o INNER JOIN
     Car_Table c
     ON c.ItemID = o.ItemID
WHERE o.Type = 'Car'
UNION ALL
SELECT o.OrderID, o.Type, o.ItemID, m.ItemDesc
FROM Order_Table o INNER JOIN
     Motorbike_Table m
     ON c.ItemID = m.ItemID
WHERE o.Type = 'Motorbike';
```

MS Access is finicky about joins, so I don't think the following works:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.Type, o.ItemID,
       NZ(c.ItemDesc, m.ItemDesc) AS ItemDesc
FROM (Order_Table o LEFT JOIN
      Car_Table c
      ON c.ItemID = o.ItemID AND o.Type = 'Car'
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Motorbike_Table m
     ON m.ItemID = o.ItemID AND o.type = 'Motorbike'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, the first one doesn't work as expected - it gives me all possible combination since the ItemID can be similar in both Car_Tbl as well as Motorbike_Tbl.

Comment: @DanielGinting . . . The first one can be easily adjusted by including a `WHERE` clause.